# How to make reusable form in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I want to show a form dynamically via passing props from component. How can I do this?

Edited..

Here is a code for my Login Component and I am using Dynamic Form Component to render the Form:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import DynamicForm from './DynamicForm';
class Login extends Component
{

constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: ''
    }
}

onChangeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
}
onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {fullname, email, password} = this.state;
    this.setState({name: fullname, email: email, password: password})
}
render() {
    let dynamicForm = [
        {
            name: 'fullname',
            type: 'text',
            label: 'Username'
        }, {
            name: 'email',
            type: 'email',
            label: 'Email'
        }, {
            name: 'password',
            type: 'password',
            label: 'Password'
        }
    ]
    return (
        <div className="col-md-12">
            <DynamicForm dynamicForm={dynamicForm}/>

        </div>
    );
}

}
export default Login;
```

And here is the Dynamic Form Component:

```
import React from 'react';

const DynamicForm = (props) => {
    return (

    <form className='login'>
        {props
            .dynamicForm
            .map((formAttr, index) => {
                return (
                    <div key={index} className="col-md-3">
                        <label>
                            {formAttr.label}
                        </label>
                        <input type={formAttr.type} name={formAttr.name}/>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
    </form>

);
}
export default DynamicForm;
```

Comment: Do you have a current implementation that you have already written? would be helpful to share what you have done for others to add on to your code or advise on it. The answer to your question depends largely on the context

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Kaushal! Could you please include the code you have written so far in the question, and elaborate a bit on what you are struggling with? It's hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Ming Jin  thank you for replying. Ok  i will add it ..